Flutter! How to scroll both parent and child elements horizontally using a duplicate PageView?
I wanted to scroll horizontally by using two PageViews, but it wasn't possible.
NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() If you use this on a child element, the child element will not scroll. I tried disabling it on only one side, but it doesn't seem to work well.
Please help if there is a way.
of course
"animateToPage"
I tried the same method but it doesn't look very natural.
I want to use natural scrolling with the pageView function.
class Position extends StatefulWidget {
 const Position({super.key});

 @override
 State<Position> createState() => _PositionState();
}

class _PositionState extends State<Position> {
 List<String> page1 = [
  "Main #1 Sub #1Page",
  "Main #1 Sub #2Page",
  "Main #1 Sub #3Page"
 ];
 List<String> page2 = [
  "Main #2 Sub #1Page",
  "Main #2 Sub #2Page",
  "Main #2 Sub #3Page"
 ];
 List<String> page3 = [
  "Main #3 Sub #1Page",
  "Main #3 Sub #2Page",
  "Main #3 Sub #3Page"
 ];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: PageView(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: [
      Center(
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: page1.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Center(child: Text(page1[index]));
          },
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: page2.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Center(child: Text(page2[index]));
          },
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: page3.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Center(child: Text(page3[index]));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}

